# Benefiting from a Jew's planting on Shabbos b'shogeg

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, hanaah-benefit

The Preface - *hakdama* to the English edition of Volume 1 of *Shmiras Shabbos k'Hilchaso* writes that if a Jew *b'shogeg* (mistakenly) plants or sows a seed on Shabbos, or anything like that where some time elapses after Shabbos before any benefit can be gotten from that *melacha*, then the result of that planting or sowing or whatever *melacha* is prohibited from benefit forever, because to prohibit the benefit for use only that Shabbos would not be penalising the violator at all, since in any case the object of the *melacha* would not be available for benefit until after Shabbos.
 My question: Would the same rule apply to something that wouldn't take as long a time to complete, like *b'shogeg* cooking something or laundering clothes, if the person started the melacha close to the end of Shabbos but the cooking or laundering wasn't completed until after Shabbos was over.  Would that food be prohibited forever just like the result of the planting?

Answer (score 1):

The Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 318,1: A Jew that cooks or does any other *Melacha*(forbiden work on Shabbos) intentionally may not benefit from it for ever, however others may benefit straight away after Shabbos:

> המבשל בשבת (או שעשה אחת משאר מלאכות) במזיד, אסור לו לעולם ולאחרים מותר למוצאי שבת מיד

The Magen Ahvraham and Mishna brura explain:

> דדוקא בעכו"ם שעושה בעינן בכדי שיעשה דחיישי' שמא יאמר לו לעשות אבל ישראל לא ישמע לו
>   When a gentile does a *melacha* for a Jew, one cannot benefit until the time it takes for that Melacha to be completed after Shabbos because of a *gezeira* (decree) in case he asks the gentile to do malacha for him in the future, but if a Jew does a Melacha there is no decree to wait as we do not expect him to listen to another Jew to sin.

The Biur Halacha says planting/sewing seed are exceptional in that they are forbidden for everyone including others that did not perform the *melacha* forever (unlike other *Melacha* e.g washing cooking which are only prohibited till Motzei Shabbos).

> ודע דלדעת השו"ע דפסק כר"י דבשוגג מותר ליהנות במו"ש **זהו בכל מלאכות דמנכר הקנס שקנסו חז"ל שלא ליהנות בו ביום עד מו"ש אבל בנוטע בשבת וה"ה בזורע דבלא"ה אין יכול ליהנות לאלתר שוגג שוה למזיד דבשניהם צריך לעקור הנטיעה** כן איתא בהדיא בגיטין נ"ד ע"ב
>   According to the Shulchan Aruch: **the very act of cooking/other Melacha *could* be completed and benefited from on Shabbos so the knas is not to benefit till Motzei shabbos. However planting which takes months/years and cannot be benefitted from on that Shabbos, the only suitable *Knas* (punishment) would be to uproot the plant and not benefit after Shabbos at all** if it was planted on Shabbos whether planted on Shabbos on purpose or by mistake.
>    So there is no difference between cooking just before Shabbos ends and cooking earlier in the day unlike planting.